# zsh echoes tab, ^A, etc

Tags: zsh

Ever since my upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10, zsh fails to recognize TAB and control characters like ^A, ^C, etc.  For instance, if I type `ema` and press TAB, zsh just inserts a tab character after the `ema`, whereas I expect it to complete the command name to `emacs`.  Similarly, pressing ctrl+A results in zsh echoing `^A` instead of moving the cursor to the beginning of line.

This happens with urxvt+zsh and gnome-terminal+zsh, but not urxvt+bash and gnome-terminal+bash.  I've tried replacing `.zshrc` with an empty file, but it made no difference.  I also replaced `/etc/zsh/zsh{env,profile,login,logout}` with empty files, but still no difference.  Reinstalling zsh didn't do any good either.

I'm at a loss as to how to debug this.  Any ideas why zsh might do this?  Can someone point to settings I should check?

Comment: AFAIK those things are controlled by the `zle` option: what does `set -o | grep zle` (run in an interactive `zsh`) say?

Comment: Ah, OK.  It says "singlelinezle    off" and "zle    off".  That explains the behaviour.  Not sure why they're off though.  Aren't they supposed to be on by default?

Comment: idk tbh - does everything start working if you set them? or is there a more fundamental problem with the module?

Comment: Yes, adding `setopt zle` to .zshrc does fix everything.  I guess I'll have to make do with this workaround, and hope I'll stumble on the real cause one day.  Thanks!